# One to one correspondance of entities when building a table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, relationship

If I have 2 items with 1-1 strong dependency then one is an attribute i.e. column in the other one's table.
E.g. if we have a movie database and each movie must have a review score (*review score is a number that represents the average score from X number of viewers*) and each review score belongs to a movie then the review score should be a column in the table Movie.
Now if the review score comes from X number of people that actually did the review then this should be part of the Movie database too as a column.
But seems weird to me because the number of people is an attribute of the review score not of the movie right?
Am I misunderstanding something in this database design approach/theory?

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: You can have de-normalized and potentially risky data by storing it that way, or you can calc each time from normalized data. There are trade-offs.

Comment: @Drew:What do you mean de-normalized? If I understand the relational theory if I add review score in the table, it is normalized. Why not?

Comment: To me a "review score" is not an attribute of a movie. The length (run-time) would be, and the title. I doubt even the producer would be in my book, as there could be many. A "review score" does not stand on its own as belonging there. Would I, Drew, probably have one there, heck yes. But I would at least highlight it as risky and make sure precautions were taken to make sure it was as accurate as possible. These aren't weapon launch codes; no one dies if the score is faulty. Just know that it could be "off"

Comment: But isn't a strong 1-1 correspondence between entities signaling that it belongs to the Movie table? If it was optional it should be another table I agree.

Comment: You can't create a movie row unless someone has watched and reviewed the thing. It gets a little silly thinking about it: *oh, we can make it nullable*. I see a lot of Home Depot products online and wonder why no one has a review in yet. I am saying don't confuse "we'd like to have" with "we must have" for a column.

Comment: But if the column can be nullable this means that the relationship is *optional* so this means another table. If the relationship is strong then this means that there is no way it can be null.

Comment: To me there is nothing strong about a movie that cannot be created unless there is a review (sorry, you can't watch it yet). And there is nothing strong about a review score from a pool of 1 or 2 people. I can't really say much more. To me, a strong is a Title. Not a wish for a review pool.

Comment: I think I see your point now. Very helpful the way you phrased it. That is probably at the core of my question/concern. So on this, does it mean that a normalized table can not have a null column? Ever?

Comment: I think it can. Others may disagree. Related, but not directly answering the question you just asked [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5222). As for normailzed, let's say I have an employee, right here in front of me. And a bunch more in the factory. They don't cease being valid data points just because I don't know their current `maritalStatus` ... ok, not a great example, because we could shoot for U=Unknown. So how about birthDate?

Comment: So what is the best balance? I mean adding it as a column in the Movie table would be a problem only in terms of extra unused space right? If we have nulls I mean

Comment: In the case of movie reviews I would not hesitate for a second to save that  score in the movie table. So you run an Event to update on occasion (like stackover flow does for the profile pages). This stuff has to be intensely fast and that is a win-win. In the case of checking account balance, ah, that is not saved so fast at the account level without some serious review. I don't care what the rollup says it is at, I care about the actual transactions.

Comment: Please edit the Question to define "review score".

Comment: @RickJames:I edited OP. Is this adequate definition?

Comment: I don't see that "normalization" is relevant to the question.

Comment: @Drew & Jim If the database holds a sum and all values it is the sum of then the sum is in a certain sense redundant in that database. Normalization deals with a certain sense of redundancy in a single table. But the sum redundancy in a straightforward design here is not the normalization redundancy. If a column always held the sum of other columns in the same row then that would be the normalization redundancy.

Comment: @ Jim (& @Drew) Normalization theory is about *relations*. Therefore there are no NULLs when doing it. However, an SQL table with a NULLable column can be replaced by a table like it with the column dropped plus a table with the column now NOT NULL and with the columns of some PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE NOT NULL column set among the other columns. The copied column set is PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE NOT NULL in the table they are copied to and form a FOREIGN KEY there that REFERENCES the other table.

Comment: You don't use the terminology of relational or ER design appropriately.  (Unfortunately ER makes *unnecessary* & restrictive distinctions beween entities, relations & (ER) attributes.) We can help you more specifically if you tell us what particular database design method/product reference you are going by. Drew & RickJames are talking reasonably about practical design tradeoffs to capture real-world situations but you don't seem to even know the terminology or method  to capture a given situation, and reaanb & myself address these more basic things. PS Please elucidate your "core" question.

Comment: @philipxy the Score is independent and redundant. It is not an attribute that belongs in the movies table. A movie as an Entity does not fail to be a movie "yet" in the absence of a review. I discredit any notion of it being a Strong relationship just because an op says it is a requirement (especially in light of the info clearly available elsewhere). I think I made that pretty clear. For speed, I would have the Score in the movie table, but with precautions. Not huge ones for this app, but a precaution just the same. I was not here to write a pontificating theory answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A:**  Have another table with (movie_id, user_id, score).  Then do

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(score), 1)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE movie_id = $movie_id
PRIMARY KEY(movie_id, user_id)
```

**Plan B:**  Keep these two columns in the movie table, or in a table with 1:1 correspondence to the movie table:  (score_count, score_sum).  Then compute the avg thus:

```
SELECT ROUND(score_sum / score_count, 1)
    FROM ...
    WHERE movie_id = $movie_id
```

Recording a new score (if a separate table) would be

```
INSERT INTO movie_scores ( movie_id, score_count score_sum )
    VALUES ($movie_id, 1, $score)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        score_count = score_count + 1,
        score_sum = score_sum + VALUES(score_sum);
PRIMARY KEY(movie_id)
```

If same table as other movie info:

```
Initialize the two columns to 0.
Deal with the case where the average is 0/0.
UPDATE movies SET
        score_count = score_count + 1,
        score_sum = score_sum + $score
    WHERE movie_id = $movie_id
```

I prefer to use a **separate table** for this (and view-counts, LIKEs, upvotes, etc), in spite of it being 1:1.  This because `movie_scores` will be updated frequently.  The traffic to that table and the traffic to `movies` are independent.  Keeping them separate cuts down on contention (in very busy systems).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use "review score" for two distinct notions: One is the average value of values that are "user scores" of a movie. The other is a thing with existence separate from such a value, where two movies with the same "review score" value could be associated with different "review score" things. There is a common everyday related thing: a *user review* of a movie, with an associated value we could call a *user (review) score* for a movie. Your review score as thing we might better call a "review averaging" of a movie, and your review score as value a "review averaging score". In your design there might be a need for review and/or review averaging things rather than just scores, eg if we associate them with other things/values like a (review's) comment or a (review averaging's) number of users. But the things are distinct from the values.

So your movies may be 1:1 with review score things. But even then different movies can have the same review score value. (And if there are movies unrated by users then a movie could have no review score value.) So we are not talking about a 1:1 correspondence between movies and review score values.

Phrases like "have a", "belongs to" "is an attribute (property) of", "associated" and "related"  are vague. Eg: You say that a review score "belongs to" a movie. But also a movie can "belong to" a review score.

These phrases beg the question. Instead, identify *what* (application) *relationship*, represented by a table (base, view or query), *you* are saying some things/values participate in. Eg: "SCORE is the review averaging score from the N user reviews of movie MOVIE", giving table (and shorthand) Movie(movie, score, n).

Only when you have identified a *particular* relationship that you are talking about do phrases like "have a" and "belongs to" or "cardinality of" even have a meaning. Eg: We can express Movie(movie, score, n) as "movie MOVIE has review score value SCORE from N user reviews" as long as we realize that that is a very specific use of "has" for just this table.

We have to decide on sufficient base relationships, each characterized by such a *predicate* (sentence template) and represented by a table, to fully describe any application situation that can arise. Eg: If a movie can have no reviews then we can use Movie for rows where "movie MOVIE has review score value SCORE from some user reviews" but not "movie MOVIE has review score value SCORE". So that would require an additional predicate/table. Whereas if a movie must have a review then those two predicates mean the same thing and we can just use Movie.

Many predicates of interest can be expressed in terms of some other, base, predicates, and their corresponding tables in terms of corresponding base tables and relation operators. These are views and queries. Eg: Consider HorrorFan(user, movie) "for some values for STARS, SCORE & N, user USER gave user score value STARS to movie MOVIE in genre 'Horror' with review score value SCORE and STARS > 2 * SCORE". It can be rephrased as "there EXISTS values for STARS, GENRE, SCORE & N, such that Review(USER, MOVIE, STARS) AND Genre(MOVIE, GENRE) AND Movie(MOVIE, SCORE, N) AND STARS > 2 * SCORE and GENRE = 'Horror'". The rows that satisfy it, ie that are in its value, are expressed by replacing table predicates by table names and certain logic operators by certain relational operators: `SELECT user, movie FROM Review NATURAL JOIN Genre NATURAL JOIN Movie WHERE STARS > 2 * SCORE and GENRE = 'Horror'`.

So stop using those vague words and start finding relevant predicates, each of which gets a table.

Answer (score 0):

From an entity-relationship point of view, don't confuse attributes with 1:1 relationships. Attributes are distinct from relationships - attributes map to value sets while relationships map between entity sets. Entity sets are key values, while value sets are non-key values.

Attributes are 1:N relations, e.g. each movie is associated with one review score, but multiple movies might have the same review score. If you find 1:1 attributes, that might indicate a natural key that wasn't identified as such.

The number of people that reviewed a movie isn't an attribute of a review score. Given a score of 8, should you be able to tell me how many people reviewed the movie? I don't think so. Rather, both review score and number of people are measurements of a review pool that you're not recording. Given a 1-1 relationship between a movie and a review pool, attributes of the review pool apply transitively to the movie. Cutting out the review pool, you can just record those attributes directly on the movie.